# ARM M1 Mac, use an Azure Container Registry in an azure app Service for a dotNet 8 api : didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start

Tags: azure, docker, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, apple-m1

I am using an apple m1.
I have a basic dotNet 8 web api that works on my local docker

Program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT") ?? "80";
builder.WebHost.UseUrls($"http://*:{port}");
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();    
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

DockerFile

```
# build
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore dependecies 
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy others files and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# run
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "BgxApi8.dll"]
```

It works on local docker

```
docker build -t bgxapi8 .
docker run -p 80:80 bgxapi8
GET {{baseUrl}} -> "It works"
```

I try to make it run on an azure web app through an Azure Container Registry
I create an Azure Container Registry named bgxapi8container
I push my local docker

```
docker tag bgxapi8:latest bgxapi8container.azurecr.io/bgxapi8:latest
docker push bgxapi8container.azurecr.io/bgxapi8:latest
```

Then from the interface I create a web app with options :
Os : Linux
Publish  : Container Docker
Option : Unique container
Image source : Azure Container Registry
Registry : bgxapi8container
Tag : latest
Start Command : nothing

When I try to reach the root of the api I have this error message: "( Application Error
If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources."

If I look at the logs , I have this

> ... 2023-12-02T09:02:39.420Z INFO  - e194839a3db8 Pull complete
> 2023-12-02T09:02:40.160Z INFO  -  Digest:
> sha256:1ac77a5b131c17b141f23e7fe360eb92d9d2d405c5e4783b23261c8f49d031c2
> 2023-12-02T09:02:40.160Z INFO  -  Status: Downloaded newer image for
> bgxapi8container.azurecr.io/bgxapi8:latest 2023-12-02T09:02:40.165Z
> INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 16 Seconds
> 2023-12-02T09:02:41.162Z INFO  - Starting container for site
> 2023-12-02T09:02:41.162Z INFO  - docker run -d --expose=80 --name
> bgxapi8_0_d872b733 -e WEBSITE_USE_DIAGNOSTIC_SERVER=false -e
> WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=bgxapi8
> -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=bgxapi8.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=d48e7722c44716b2d3b260fd39937cd26b4df2c1aad200418e83e1648d9c8bd5
> bgxapi8container.azurecr.io/bgxapi8:latest  2023-12-02T09:02:41.162Z
> INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container. Please use
> https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container
> logs here. 2023-12-02T09:02:43.219Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request
> to container bgxapi8_0_d872b733 for site bgxapi8
> 2023-12-02T09:02:43.244Z ERROR - Container bgxapi8_0_d872b733 for site
> bgxapi8 has exited, failing site start 2023-12-02T09:02:43.249Z ERROR
>
> - Container bgxapi8_0_d872b733 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
>   2023-12-02T09:02:43.280Z INFO  - Stopping site bgxapi8 because it
>   failed during startup.

Do you know what is the issue and how to solve it please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You answered your question when you mentioned that you're building the image on an Apple M1. This results in an image that can run on ARM platforms and currently, App Service only supports AMD64.

On a M1 Mac, you can build multiarch containers using Buildx. This way, you can build an AMD64 version of your container that you'll be able to deploy on Container Apps. [Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/)

Another option is to build the container image using Azure Container Registry. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-acr-build)